# Can you tamper with an alarm spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Is it possible to change the password of an alarm spell or similar after it has been cast?

Similar spells include

- Invisibility Alarm

Comment: You mean specifically without ending the ongoing magical effect?  Does using time travel to alter the caster's choices count?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I had not considered time travel as those are high level spells. I was thinking more along the lines of disable device, spellcraft, UMD,...

Comment: Again, just ending the spell and putting it up again isn't allowed?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer No. Say a caster created a perm mental alarm on an area, and someone changed the password so that no one knows how to bypass it. One example.

Answer (score 1):

## There are no rules to alter existing magical effects

But this doesn't mean existing rules aren't similar or close enough to be applied to this situation. Lets look at Counterspells rules. While this is for normally stopping a magical effect, lets look at the similarities.

> To (Counterspell), you must (..) cast an appropriate spell. As a general rule, a spell can only counter itself. If you are able to cast the same spell and you have it prepared (or have a slot of the appropriate level available), you cast it, creating a counterspell effect. If the target is within range, both spells automatically negate each other with no other results.

Now while this is for canceling a spell while it is being cast. Id imagine with enough added difficulty, you could lightly modify spells.

**Disable device** also has rules for disabling magic trap effects. As alarm makes a ward, and is not actually invisible, a character suffeciently skilled at disabling traps, and arcane know-how may be able to alter the "Warding" of alarm.

**Both of these are not explicitly in the rules. Talk with GM about implementing these before assuming they are usable.**